# Set display size greater than physical

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

I need to make a screenshot of a program running on Windows 10, which should be printed on a banner that is several meters wide and high.

Making the screenshot on my display with 1920*1080 resolution will not be sufficient for this print. I attached a second display with 1920*1080 to the computer and used [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) so I was able to stretch the window across both displays. This screenshot is better, but is it possible to define a display resolution, which is bigger than the maximum physical one? I think scrollbars would be no problem.

Comment: "is it possible to define a display resolution which is bigger than the maximum physical one" - You could do this but your monitor would display it, which would make it tough, to take your screenshot.  You will have to take the approach you have taken, define multiple monitors as a single unified display, this will allow you to set the resolution of that single display larger then any individual display could handle.  How that can be accomplished really depends on the software at your disposal and your hardware.

Comment: I need to make a Screenshot of a GPX track, actuall i use "GPXSee" to display it. Actuall I'm using a Dell Notebook with Intel HD grafic.

Comment: So you are going to be limited to a maximum resolution, that will be restricted by the number of external monitors, your notebook can actually support.

Comment: You will get better results if you ask how to solve your actual problem, instead of how to implement your proposed solution. For more information see the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445).

Answer (score 1):

Remote Desktop solution:

#### You can connect to your computer via Remote Desktop with custom resolution.

First, connect normally and save **.rdp** file.
Second, using plain text editor, create or edit the following settings in your **.rdp** file:

```
desktopwidth:i:3000
desktopheight:i:2000
```

where values `3000` and `2000` are sample values illustrating higher resolution, adjust them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I used my old notebook, running Debian. Here it's just one command to be executed in a shell:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --rate 60 --mode 1366x768 --fb 6000x5000 --panning 6000x5000
```

to have a resolution i need. I didn't tried this bevore, because it only has a physical resulution of 1366x768.
GPXSee runs also on Linux, so i was able to get a screenshot without connecting an extra display, installing additional SW, ... Everything works out of the box as i expected.

Comment: I am glad that my solution has shown you how you can access your computer from another computer you find at home and adjust the resolution as part of remote access.

Comment: It would be fine if Windows could do this "out of the box"

Comment: no-one typically needs this and if yes, the workaround is easy, so why put tens of thousands dollars into such a niche functionality? No standard (sane) software company would do that.

Comment: "easy" is relative, for me it was impossible, using a second Display or Computer is no solution. MS-Software in my eyes has so much funktions/features "no-one typically needs", that this is no argument.
My personel problem is solved, possible solutions are documented, so we should close this thread.

Comment: Let's close the thread, mark the most helpful answer, if possible. I don't know what features "no-one typically needs" did you mean, but OK. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an NVidia card, you can actually run the display at higher than physical resolution by adding a custom display profile.

Using the NVidia Control Panel, switch from monitor scaling to GPU scaling:

[image: Switch from monitor scaling to GPU scaling]

Go to "Change resolution" and click "Customize":

[image: Add a custom resolution]

Check "Enable resolutions not supported by the display" and click "Create custom resolution":

[image: Create custom resolution]

Manually input the width and height in pixels, e.g. 2 x your monitor's physical resolution:

[image: Manually input the width and height]

Your custom resolution should now be available to choose from the regular "Display Settings" control panel in Windows - from there, you probably also want to change the "Scale and Layout" e.g. to 200% since native UI elements will be really small otherwise.

**NOTE:** this does have performance implications - you're using more video memory, and drawing the user interface at this resolution puts more strain on both your CPU and GPU. You probably want to switch to the higher resolution only for special occasions like taking screenshots, then switch back to native resolution for everyday use.

Here's a video showing everything step-by-step:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUdqjdXKUrQ

Comment: looks good, but I'm using Intel "on board" graphics :-(

Comment: @roli yes, I recently switched to an Intel GPU as well - I don't know of any way to do it with the Intel drivers. :-/